# How to execute a calculation php script on html form

Tags: php, html

I make a PHP script for calculation based on pricelist. My script work powerful, but the problem is: I must enter the value directly in source code. I wouldlike to offer end-user the opportunity to use my script without any code by a simply fill html form.

I have difficulty to link my php script on the form to make this calculation.

Bellow my source code:

1. FORM

   ```
    <center>
        <form action="samepage.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="amount" value="0"/>F
       <input name="button" type="submit" id="button" value="CALCULATE"  />         
      </form>

       <br>
   ```
2. PHP SCRIPT

   **Corresponding your Amount, YOU MUST PAY:** 
     // How to remplace 500 value with form value?

   // THE PRICELIST PHP SCRIPT

   ```
   <?php
   if($montant <= 5000){ // If the amount are <= to 500, 200 must add
     echo $montant + 200;
   F </h2>
       </center>
   ```

   I need your help, Thanks in advance!

---

I have difficulty to link my php script on the form to make this calculation.

Comment: If the calculation is based on above If() - Else() block then that can be done with the hrlp of Javascript also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the php code is on the same page then you need to do this.

```
<center>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="amount" placeholder="0" />F
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="CALCULATE"/>
        </form>
    <br>
    <strong>Corresponding your Amount, YOU MUST PAY: </strong><br><h2>
        <?php 

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $montant = $_POST['amount'];
            if ($montant <= 5000) {
                echo $montant + 200;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 10000) {
                echo $montant + 400;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 15000) {
                echo $montant + 600;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 25000) {
                echo $montant + 900;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 35000) {
                echo $montant + 1100;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 50000) {
                echo $montant + 1200;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 75000) {
                echo $montant + 1700;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 100000) {
                echo $montant + 2000;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 150000) {
                echo $montant + 2200;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 200000) {
                echo $montant + 2400;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 250000) {
                echo $montant + 2900;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 300000) {
                echo $montant + 3900;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 400000) {
                echo $montant + 4900;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 200000) {
                echo $montant + 2400;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 750000) {
                echo $montant + 7400;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 1000000) {
                echo $montant + 9900;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 2000000) {
                echo $montant + 14900;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 3000000) {
                echo $montant + 19900;
            }else{

            }
        }
?>
        F</h2>
</center>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much Ramu! I have this problem for 2days ago!

Comment: And also, What code use if the PHP code are on the other page?

Answer (score 1):

Hello All and thanks you so much for your useful help!

Now I wouldlike to execute the same script on 2 page.

The first page containt the form and the second the PHP script.

My is/else collection is easy to understand, I continue to use that. What modification must I do to execute the same script on 2 page please?

I think to do this:

FIRST PAGE:

```
<form action="next-page.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="amount" placeholder="0" />F
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="CALCULATE"/>
        </form>
```

SECOND PAGE

```
    <strong>Corresponding your Amount, YOU MUST PAY: </strong><br><h2>
        <?php 

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $montant = $_POST['amount'];
            if ($montant <= 5000) {
                echo $montant + 200;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 10000) {
                echo $montant + 400;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 15000) {
                echo $montant + 600;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 25000) {
                echo $montant + 900;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 35000) {
                echo $montant + 1100;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 50000) {
                echo $montant + 1200;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 75000) {
                echo $montant + 1700;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 100000) {
                echo $montant + 2000;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 150000) {
                echo $montant + 2200;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 200000) {
                echo $montant + 2400;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 250000) {
                echo $montant + 2900;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 300000) {
                echo $montant + 3900;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 400000) {
                echo $montant + 4900;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 200000) {
                echo $montant + 2400;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 750000) {
                echo $montant + 7400;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 1000000) {
                echo $montant + 9900;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 2000000) {
                echo $montant + 14900;
            } else
            if ($montant <= 3000000) {
                echo $montant + 19900;
            }else{

            }
        }
?>
        F</h2>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're posting back to the same page, you can use the following:

```
<?php if ($_POST['amount']) {
        $montant = (float) $_POST['amount']; // Number cast for security, use (int) to remove decimals
    } else {
        $montant = 500;
    } // How to remplace 500 value on the form value  ?>
```

This can also be done in shorthand as follows:

```
<?php $montant = $_POST['amount'] ? (float) $_POST['amount'] : 500; ?>
```

I know you didn't ask, but you could also simplify your if/else collection a few ways, such as using an array then looping it:

```
<?php $vals = array(3000000 => 19900, 2000000 => 14900, 1000000 => 9900); //etc
foreach ($vals as $total => $additional) {
    // Working down from highest to lowest until we match
    if ($montant <= $total) {
        $montant += $additional; 
        break; // Exit when found
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks you for this! Now I wouldlike to execute the same script on 2 page. The first page containt the form and the second the PHP script. My is/else collection is easy to understand, I continue to use that. What modification must I do to execute the same script on 2 page please?